# Node.js weird exectution order and undefined result when doing select query

Tags: node.js

I am trying to select data from mysql database, and it has some issues.
It seems, that select query is working fine, in debug I can see, that there are results, but when I return them, there's nothing.

I have that folder structure:

```
includes\database\createConnection.js
includes\database\databaseOperations.js
includes\routings.js
app.js
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const appConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./configs/appconfig.json")))
const routings = require(path.resolve("./includes/routings.js"));

app.use(express.static("public"))

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://${appConfig.host}:${appConfig.port}`);
});

app.get('/testdb',(req,res)=>{
    routings.testdb(req,res);
    res.status(200);
});
```

createConnection.js

```
function connectToDatabase(){
    const fs = require('fs')
    const mysql = require('mysql')
    const path = require('path');

    const dbConfig = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./configs/dbconfig.json")))

    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: dbConfig.host,
        port: dbConfig.port,
        user: dbConfig.username,
        password: dbConfig.password,
        database: dbConfig.database
    })

    connection.connect(function(error){
        if(error) throw error;
    });
    return connection;
}

module.exports = {connectToDatabase}
```

databaseOperations.js

```
function dbExec(connection,query){
    connection.query(query, function(err,result,fields){
      if(err) console.log("There was an error, while doing select query: " + query);
      console.log("Result from dbexec: " + result);
      return result;
   });
}

function selectUser(connection,username){
    let query = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '${username}'`;
    let userdata = dbExec(connection,query);
    console.log("From select user: " + userdata);
    return userdata;
}

module.exports = {selectUser};
```

routings.js

```
function testdb(req,res){
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    const testing = require(path.resolve("./includes/database/createConnection.js"));
    const dbo = require(path.resolve("./includes/database/databaseOperations.js"));

    let connection = testing.connectToDatabase();
    let results = dbo.selectUser(connection,"raitis");
    console.log(results);

    return (req,res) =>{
        res.send(results);
    }
}   

module.exports = {testdb}
```

Expected result:

User data returned as an JSON object in a response to client

Actual result:

No data in response, undefined object
In debug console logs I get:

```
Server is running on http://127.0.0.1:3000
app.js:11
From select user: undefined
includes/database/databaseOperations.js:12
undefined
includes/routings.js:9
Result from dbexec: [object Object]
```

Which seems really weird, because by that log, it first executes `selectUser()` without executing `dbExec()` afterwards, gets back to `routings.js` does console log there, and only after that, it shows console log from `dbExec()`

What I am doing wrong here? :)
My data in MySQL -

## id, username, password, useralias, sessionid

'0', 'raitis', '123', 'admin', '333'

Comment: It seems you're not familiar with how asynchronous code works in Node.js. You may want to start with some tutorials on that subject before diving into more complex projects.

Answer (score 0):

Your selectUser function does not receive retrun from your dbExec function.

You have two possibilities :
use async / await :

```
async function dbExec(connection,query){
    connection.query(query, function(err,result,fields){
      if(err) console.log("There was an error, while doing select query: " + query);
      console.log("Result from dbexec: " + result);
      return result;
   });
}

async function selectUser(connection,username){
    let query = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '${username}'`;
    let userdata = await dbExec(connection,query);
    console.log("From select user: " + userdata);
    return userdata;
}
```

use callback function

```
function dbExec(connection,query,callback){
    connection.query(query, function(err,result,fields){
      if(err) console.log("There was an error, while doing select query: " + query);
      console.log("Result from dbexec: " + result);
      return result;
   });
}

function selectUser(connection,username){
    let query = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '${username}'`;
    dbExec(connection,query,function(result) {
      console.log("From select user: " + result);
      return result;
    });
}
```

Comment: Your async implementation of `dbExec` still doesn't return anything.